# How to check if a create-react-app project has been ejected or not?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm working on a project built by someone else. I know it was bootstrapped by create-react-app because it says so in README.md.

However, I'm not sure if it has been ejected or not. There are many posts out there teaching you how to actually eject it, but I failed to find a way to check it in the first place. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: " I'm not sure if it has been ejected or not" just try to create a simple project and eject it. You will see some clear differences there... :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thank you very much! :)

Comment: The most noticeable difference IMHO would be the absence of `eject` command in `package.json#scripts` section though ;)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Sure it is! Why didn't I think of that!

Answer (score 10):

Some immediate giveaways that a `create-react-app` project has been ejected:

- The dependencies field in `package.json` no longer contains `react-scripts`. Instead, it is populated with many additional packages like Babel, Eslint, Jess, Webpack and various Webpack loaders.
- The absence of `eject` script.
- The `start`, `build` and `test` no longer follows this format `react-scripts start`, `react-scripts build` etc.
- A new directory named `config` appears.

Just sharing because you may or may not see all of these signs in your project as they were probably ejected a long time ago. I hope no one will spend two hours wondering why a certain package didn't work only to discover that the project has been ejected and the package only works with unejected ones.

Answer (score 4):

Many thanks to @YuryTarabanko!

So I tried creating another project using CRA and ejecting it. Right after the ejection, a new directory called `config` popped up and there were some modifications in other directories, too.

Then I took a look at the project I'm actually interested in. The `config` directory is right there, with a structure similar to that `config` dir in the new project that popped up after the ejection. So I'm sure this project has been ejected, too!

### Edit:

As Yuri pointed out in the comment:

> The most noticeable difference IMHO would be the absence of eject command in package.json#scripts section though ;)

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat agree with the script in package.json, but it could have easily been removed. If the project is in a repo, you should be able to look at the history of a few files to be certain.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30712972)